# Converting PNG to JPG with UIImage giving odd result

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

My `UIImage` holds a .png image loaded from disk and is used to set backgroundColor in a background view. That works.

I now want to convert to .JPG to remove transparency / alpha channel. I have tried a few variations, but here's an example:

```
var orgImage: UIImage? = nil;
var newImage: UIImage? = nil;
orgImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: "...");
let tmpData: NSData? = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(orgImage!, 1.0);
newImage = UIImage(data: tmpData);
```

However, when using `newImage` for the background, the image appears zoomed in. I don't want that. I want the same image, simply converted to JPG.

The code I use for this is:

```
// works
myView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: orgImage!)

// appears zoomed/scaled
myView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: newImage!)
```

I have tried (for testing purposes) to do a PNG to PNG (over disk or NSData) and saving/loading to/from disk instead. All tests yielding the same result.

Any idea what I am doing wrong? I am testing in iOS simulator.

Comment: Your issue has nothing to do with the format conversion. Update your question with details about how you make use of the new image.

Comment: @rmaddy I haven't looked correctly at the code and I thought the problem would be connected with image scale. Which probably is anyway.

Comment: @rmaddy I have included the code now.